# Как задать в ViewPagerAdapter страницу по умолчанию?

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager

Есть ли возможность задать в адаптере для пейджера номер страницы по умолчанию **ДО** того, как адаптер будет прицеплен к пейджеру, чтобы отрисовка страниц шла **НЕ** в порядке `0, 1, need - 1, need, need + 1`, а сразу начиналась с `need - 1, need, need + 1` ?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31268934/5330439)

Comment: то, что нужно, спасибо

Comment: Лучше добавьте решение в виде ответа. А в самом вопросе оставьте только вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В соответствии с ответом TimurVI решение выглядит так

```
public static void foolViewPager(ViewPager pager, PagerAdapter adapter, int position) {
    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    pager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

Для пейджера задается пустой адаптер, что позволяет использовать `pager.setCurrentItem(int)`. В результате значение пишется в `private` поле `mRestoredCurItem` `ViewPager`'a и используется в `restoreState` `ViewPager`'а, когда мы добавляем ему правильный адаптер. В результате отрисовка идет сразу с нужной страницы. Плюс решения в том, что мы для обращения кэтому полю не используем рефлекшн, а стало быть нам не надо совершать танцев с бубном вокруг прогварда